# Certificate error for fastly.net on some ads

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

It looks like one of the ad network systems is using a certificate incorrectly. It shows up very infrequently, but when it does Safari complains vigorously.

I think this is the offending snippet:

```
<script>$(window).load(function () {
  $('#teststackoverflow').attr(
    'src', 'https://teststackoverflow.com.global.prod.fastly.net/?test=Fastly_21\u0026size=9000'); 
  });
</script>
```

That name is not one of the allowed names for the certificate. You can easily verify this with:

```
 curl https://teststackoverflow.com.global.prod.fastly.net
```

Comment: Ran into the same thing myself just now, so I can reproduce this.

Comment: You do have to reload a bunch of times for the broken one to enter the rotation, but I've been hit with it by chance already more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed. Was an interim issue caused by some testing I was doing. Should've only lasted a few minutes.

Thanks for reporting!